# New install on my PC

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to load ubuntu on my PC.  I have a AMD 64 chip.  When I run the boot DVD I just get a blank screen.  Would it be a hardware problem that will not allow ubuntu to load?

Comment: Did you set the CD/DVD optical drive to come first in the BIOS setup utility Boot Device Priority?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should elaborate you question with more details, but I could recommend some steps below:

1. Before you boot Ubuntu DVD live, you must ensure that it is Ubuntu
   64bit version (because yours is AMD64).
2. Then boot with the DVD and pressing a special keyboard key to display booting otions menu (on my nephew  ASUS laptop, it is ESC key). on
   booting options, choose DVD option.

   (Note: you can also set the booting optio priority from BIOS setup utiliy)